# php create non-ASCII directory on wampserver (windows)

Tags: php, wampserver, mkdir

how create directory with non-ASCII names on  wampserver (windows) ?

Comment: Windows doesn't support non-ASCII directory names particularly well, and other platforms vary widely; so it's always more sensible to restrict your directory names to ASCII characters

Comment: @MarkBaker: Windows has no problem with non-ASCII directory names, it just doesn't default to UTF-8 for the C-style file system manipulation functions. To deal with full Unicode paths you have to go through the widechar versions of the functions, like [_wmkdir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw(v=vs.100).aspx) (or the widechar entry points of the Win32 API; [CreateDirectoryW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx))

Comment: It still saves a lot of aggravation if ASCII is used for filenames, and it's cross-platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'سسسس';
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
     $str = iconv( "UTF-8", "Windows-1256", $str );
}
mkdir( $str );
```

This will work if your `iconv` supports `Windows-1256` and the PHP file containing the string literal `'سسسس'` is saved in UTF-8.